# Query not working in SQLReader

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, console-application

I have this code in my project to run a query and paste it in to Excel.  I currently have it working in one project (with a different query) but now I am trying to get it to work with a different query and it will not work.  However, if I run the query in SQL server it works.

Here is the query:

```
public static string Query (DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
     //string Query = "SELECT * from access";
     string Query = "SELECT distinct s.first_nme + ' ' + s.last_nme as Student ,convert(Date, e.entrydate) as date ,od.u_order_id as 'Order#'";
     Query = Query + " " + "FROM enrollment e";
     Query = Query + " " + "join registration r on e.u_registration_id = r.u_registration_id";
     Query = Query + " " + "join student s on r.u_student_id = s.u_student_id";
     Query = Query + " " + "join order_pack_list opl on r.u_ord_pack_list_id = opl.u_ord_pack_list_id";
     Query = Query + " " + "join product p on opl.u_product_id = p.u_product_id";
     Query = Query + " " + "join order_detail od on opl.u_order_detail_id = od.u_order_detail_id";
     Query = Query + " " + "where e.entrydate >= " + startDate.ToString();
     Query = Query + " " + "and e.entrydate <= " + endDate.ToString();
     Query = Query + " " + "and p.prod_type_cd = 'B' and opl.modify_user_id = 'STCUSA30'";
     Query = Query + " " + "order by Student";

     return Query;
}
```

The reason there is a commented out line on the top is to test - when I run that simple query, it will not crash.

And here is the code I use to get the dates (and run the query), to rule that out as an issue:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today;

SqlDataReader rdr = null;

try
{

     // 2. Open the connection
     conn.Open();

     string query = Query(startDate, endDate);

     // 3. Pass the connection to a command object
     using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
     {
           //
           // 4. Use the connection
           //

           // get query results
           rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

and it crashes on the rdr line saying,

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near '12'.

I looked online and there are no answers that pertain to my situation (that I can tell).

Answer (score 2):

Based on your error, you could see how this could potentially render a query that looks like the following, which is invalid SQL (as these constant values need to be wrapped in quotes):

```
WHERE e.entryDate >= 12/31/2016
```

This is occurring because you are concatenating your `DateTime` object as a string, but since it isn't wrapped in quotes, it's blowing up. You could easily add quotes to help prevent this :

```
Query = Query + " " + "where e.entrydate >= '" + startDate.ToString() + "' ";
Query = Query + " " + "and e.entrydate <= " + endDate.ToString() + "' ";;
```

**A Better Approach: Parameterization**

The bigger issue here is that you should be using parameterization to populate these values to avoid these types of issues (and any possibility of SQL Injection) :

```
Query = Query + " " + "where e.entrydate >= @start";
Query = Query + " " + "and e.entrydate <= @end";
```

And then adding these values as parameters prior to executing your query :

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
{
       // Add your parameters
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@start",startDate);
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@end",endDate);

       // Execute here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  Oddly enough I did not use the single quotes in my other app and it worked.

Comment: You must of been using ints in your other app which do not require quotes